# Advanced Filtering Copy certain columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Advanced Filtering and the code is copying all the filtered rows to a new tab. Now I don't want to copy everything but only selected columns by range.

```
Sheets("Data").Range("Tabel1[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
Sheets("Data").Range("AG1:AL2"),CopyToRange:=Sheets(“Filter”).Range(“B10″), Unique:=True
```

I've tried something like this but there is a syntax error:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("Tabel1[#All]").AdvancedFilter, CriteriaRange:= _
Sheets("Data").Range("AG1:AL2"),Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Copy _
destination:=Sheets("Filter").Range("B10"),Unique:=True
```

Any ideas how to select certain columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can check, this way too works.

```
Sub Try()  

Sheets("Data1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("$A$1:$P$16214").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="AMERICA"
'Autofilter Field refers to Column. this case i am applying filter in 2nd column
Range("A1:P16214").Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data2").Select
Range("A1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```